# Reset company logo for all job listings in wp job manager

Tags: wordpress

I did import all of my job listings from one site to another, and I have problem with company logo image url, what I'm trying to do is to reset company logo for all job listings, so set it using a filter, or find a way to import the images correctly.

```html
/* This code will set the default company logo, but if there is already existing logo it will not work*/

add_filter( 'job_manager_default_company_logo', 'smyles_custom_job_manager_logo' );
function smyles_custom_job_manager_logo( $logo_url ){
 // Change the value below to match the filename of the custom logo you want to use
 // Place the file in a /images/ directory in your child theme's root directory.
 // The example provided assumes "/images/custom_logo.png" exists in your child theme
 $filename = 'logo_clear.png';
 
 $logo_url = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/' . $filename;
 
 return $logo_url;
 
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I did export all of my job listings from one site to another, and the import failed to include the conpany logo image url. So I think using the default company log will a better option.